# Logic error, assigning value to different type

Tags: java, methods, char, integer

I need some help answering my own question, so I need to assign a int value to a character. I have looked and look through the api. I can not think of what I should do. I need to assign the character and int value designated by the user, he/she will assign any integer to and char they desire. At first I thought to type cast, but I can not get my type cast to work correctly. any ideas?

```html
e.g.

F = 56
H = -25
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Also, `char` can't be negative.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is already predefined values associated to characters and this is related to encoding. For example the value for A is 65, B 66, ... and you can't reprogramme it arbitrarly except by using a very low level programming technics. Now if you want to associate int values to characters you can use a Map.

for example

```
Map<Character, Integer> charValues = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
charValues.put('H',-25);
charValues.put('F', 56);
```

And later while processing the map you can use for example

```
int valueForH = charValues.get('H');
```

**The autoboxing and auto unboxing capacities of Java allows you to go transparently from the Character/Integer reference types to char/int value types**

You can use this in an interactive fashion with the user via a main method or other method. Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<Character, Integer> charValues = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a character and the corresponding value...");
        String data = sc.next();
        if ("exit".equals(data)) {
            break;
        }
        char car = data.charAt(0);

        int correspondingValue = sc.nextInt();
        charValues.put(car, correspondingValue);

    }

    // Here after exit you can use charValues.get(key) to get the int value    associated with the key (a char value)

}
```